# How to have a Gradle task set shell set environment variables?

Tags: gradle, environment-variables

I have a Gradle task which invokes a shell script which sets some environment variables. These variables are used by another shell script which is also invoked by Gradle as another task. However, the second task cannot view these variables. What is wrong and how do I actually achieve my required behavior?

I am working in Unix/Linux. Both the Gradle tasks are basically Exec type of tasks.

Assuming, I am ready to out source the work done by the first shell script (setting env variables) to Gradle. How can I make the second shell script pick up these variables?

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting environ variables you want to share? Try with export keyword, as suggested in the following example:

```
$ cat a.sh
#! /bin/sh
export VAR=val
/path/to/b.sh

$ cat b.sh
#! /bin/sh
echo $VAR
```

When you execute a.sh the output "val" is printed on the screen.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Correct. Something like `setenv VAR var`. My `var's` are actually directory paths. Like for eg, `setenv ROOT_PATH ./my_root_path`

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. I have a Gradle task which runs a shell script which sets environment variables . I want to use these variables in another shell script which is run by another Gradle task

Comment: In my example I am defining and exporting the environ variable VAR in the a.sh shell script, and using that A variable in b.sh shell script. If you don't use export keyword in my example, it doesn't work. Check it.